# 4SQL - Query to select date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, one is table A which stores Resources Assign to work for a certain period.  The structure is as below

```
Name      StartDate                    EndDate
 Tan       2015-04-01 08:30:00.000     2015-04-01 16:30:00.000
 Max       2015-04-01 08:30:00.000     2015-04-01 16:30:00.000
 Alan      2015-04-01 16:30:00.000     2015-04-02 00:30:00.000
```

The second table B stores the item process time.  The structure is as below

```
 Item    ProcessStartDate            ProcessEndDate
 V       2015-04-01 09:30:10.000     2015-04-01 09:34:45.000
 Q       2015-04-01 10:39:01.000     2015-04-01 10:41:11.000
 W       2015-04-01 11:44:00.000     2015-04-01 11:46:25.000
 A       2015-04-01 16:40:10.000     2015-04-01 16:42:45.000
 B       2015-04-01 16:43:01.000     2015-04-01 16:45:11.000
 C       2015-04-01 16:47:00.000     2015-04-01 16:49:25.000
```

I need to select the item which process in 2015-04-01 16:40:00 and 2015-04-01 17:30:59.  Beside that I need to know how many resource is assigned to process the item in that period of time.  I only know the start date is 2015-04-01 16:00:00 and end date is 2015-04-01 17:30:59.  How I can select the data from both tables.  There is no need for JOIN, just seperate selections.

Another item process time is in 2015-04-01 10:00:00 and 2015-04-04 11:50:59.

The result expected is

```
   Name      StartDate                    EndDate
   Alan      2015-04-01 16:30:00.000     2015-04-02 00:30:00.000

   Item    ProcessStartDate            ProcessEndDate
   A       2015-04-01 16:30:10.000     2015-04-01 16:32:45.000
   B       2015-04-01 16:33:01.000     2015-04-01 16:35:11.000
   C       2015-04-01 16:37:00.000     2015-04-02 16:39:25.000
```

Scenario 2 expected result

```
   Name      StartDate                    EndDate
   Tan       2015-04-01 08:30:00.000     2015-04-01 16:30:00.000
   Max       2015-04-01 08:30:00.000     2015-04-01 16:30:00.000

    Item    ProcessStartDate            ProcessEndDate     
    Q       2015-04-01 10:39:01.000     2015-04-01 10:41:11.000
    W       2015-04-01 11:44:00.000     2015-04-01 11:46:25.000
```

I has modified a bit the requirement.
Please Help.

Comment: If you only query by the dates then use BETWEEN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 in both queries.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in the question and info provided.  I has change the item process time to 2015-04-01 16:40:00 and 2015-04-01 17:30:59.  I has try                                                                                                   select * from tableB where ProcessStartDate>'2015-04-01 16:40:00' 
      and ProcessEndDate<'2015-04-01 17:30:59'                                                                                                           SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE StartDate>='2015-04-01 16:40:00' 
AND EndDate<='2015-04-01 17:30:59'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select *
from tableB
where ProcessStartDate>'2015-04-01 16:00:00' 
      and 
      ProcessEndDate<'2015-04-01 17:30:59'
```

To get result for tableA you have two option depending on what you need to do.

- They are not connected, do the same thing. (change to tableA)
- They are connected, you need to use a key between them and select the proper part from tableA which correspond to those ProcessDates.

Comment: If the StartDate is change to 2015-04-01 16:40:00, the table A cannot be select.  This is the problem I face.  Table A and B no key related together.  And I can't figure out what key can use to link it up.  Table A just a table to store the worker shift time.  Table B is store the item process info.  Any idea what key i can use?